# Differential equation for path in radial field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polar-coordinates, parametrization

Suppose that in a plane parallel to the yz-plane, the index of refraction $n$ is a function of the distance from the origin, $R$, i.e., $n = n(R)$.

We know that (e.g., http://aty.sdsu.edu/explain/atmos_refr/invariant.html), that $n(R)R\sin\theta = \mathrm{constant}$ at every point, where $\theta$ is analogous to the "$z$" angles shown in the diagram:[image]

With the relation above I have the information to calculate $\theta$ at every point, but I'd like to recast it into a differential equation that gives me the path of a ray in terms of $y$ and $z$. Is it possible to find a form for $\frac{dz}{dy}$? I could write, for instance, $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)$. Or would I have to parametrize $y$ and $z$? How would I do this? What is the easiest way of numerically finding the path?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to work in polar coordinates and then convert back to Cartesian if necessary.

Specifically, consider the $\{\log w\}$ plane (or rather, strip) for $w = y + iz$. The circles will map to horizontal lines $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}} \log w = \mathrm{const}$, the ray you need to find will map to... well, something, but because the logarithm is conformal, the *angles* between the two at each point will stay the same. Therefore, for $\log(y + iz) = \log R + i\phi$, you will get (schematically)
$$n(R)R\sin(\arctan d\phi/d\log R) = C,$$
$$d\phi/d\log R = \tan\arcsin(C / n(R)R) = \sqrt{[n(R)R/C]^2 - 1}\,,$$
$$d\phi/dR = \sqrt{[n(R)/C]^2 - R^2}\,,$$
which looks a lot more tractable to me.